# "Parsing error: Unexpected token => eslint"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, express

I am seeing this error in my index.js file in VSC which looks to be caused by the app.post request.

I've attempted different parsing options in regards to eslint and emca but still aren't getting anywhere.

Appreciate any input.

**Parsing error: Unexpected token => eslint**

index.js

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const stripe = require("stripe")("hidden");

// Setting Up the API

// - App Config
const app = express();

// - Middlewares
app.use(cors({ origin: true }));
app.use(express.json());

// - API routes
app.get("/", (request, response) => response.status(200).send("hello world"));

app.post("/payments/create", async (request, response) => {
  const total = request.query.total;

  console.log("Payment Request Recieved for this amount >>> ", total);

  const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    amount: total, // subunits of the currency
    currency: "usd",
  });

  // OK - Created
  response.status(201).send({
    clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
  });
});


// - Listen command
exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.8.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.14.1",
    "stripe": "^8.174.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.5",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "7.15.4",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.25.1",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

And then this is my  .eslintrc.js file

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    es6: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "eslint: recommended",
    "google",
    "plugin: react/recommended",
  ],
  rules: {
    quotes: ["error", "double"],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're missing `parser: @babel/eslint-parser` from your eslintrc